# C# solution build via msbuild fails during GitLab CI but ERRORLEVEL is 0

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration, gitlab, solution

In my CI procces on GitLab I use batch file, that builds c# solution via msbuild this way:

```
call "%MSBUILD_PATH%\msbuild.exe" %CURRENT_DIR%\MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" /m /r:true /v:minimal /nodereuse:false /p:BuildProjectReferences=true

if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :HANDLEFAIL
```

When build of some projects in MySolution.sln fails, for some reason ERRORLEVEL is still 0.

In other words - build failed but batch execution continues and at the end of this CI job I may get a successful result as if there were no errors.

I've managed to fix this problem on my local machine by adding `/p:StopOnFirstFailure=true` parameter or by removing `/m` (disabling parallel build). For some reason neither of this two methods fix this problem in GitLab CI.

Is there any way to fix it?

Building by separate projects isn't reasonable solution in this case.

Comment: Do the builds fail when you build the same code outside Gitlab? And if they do, is ERRORLEVEL still 0 or not?

Comment: If ran locally it gives ERRORLEVEL 0. Removing `/m` parameter or adding `/p:StopOnFirstFailure=true` changes it to 1. But only when I run it on local machine.

Comment: Build fails as I use broken version of projects to test this problem.

Comment: what do you mean 'broken version' ?

Comment: I mean a commit that should fail. It has incorrect project reference in a project file, that is a part of MySolution.sln.

Comment: Try without the `call`, you never know, and it's not needed anyway. Does it happen for all kinds of errors or just incorrect project references? Have you tried contacting gitlab support? It might very well be their doing, I've had similar problems using Powershell on Appveyor just to name something.

Comment: Removing `calls` doesn't help. Haven't tested this case with any other kind of error.